# Gensim Tfidf model is returning empty weights list

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I am extracting tweets of Donald Trump and I want to use `tfidf` with `gensim` to get the weight of each token. But the last code section is returning an empty result

```
import pandas as pd 
df=pd.read_csv("/content/trumptweets.csv")
df=df.to_string()
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from collections import Counter
import nltk 
nltk.download('punkt')
nltk.download('stopwords')
tokenized_text = word_tokenize(df)
print(tokenized_text)
#change to lower case
lower_case = [t.lower() for t in tokenized_text]
print(lower_case)
# remove stop words 
no_stops = [k for k in lower_case 
            if k not in stopwords.words('english')]
# keep only alphabetic words
alpha = [ t for t in no_stops 
         if t.isalpha()]
print(alpha)

# lemmatize 
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
import nltk
nltk.download('wordnet')
lem = WordNetLemmatizer()
lemmat = [lem.lemmatize(t) for t in alpha]
#Counter(lemmat).most_common(5)

# import dictionary
#get indices and related token name 
from gensim.corpora.dictionary import Dictionary
dictionary = Dictionary([lemmat])
dictionary.token2id

# get Indices and frequency
corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(doc) for doc in [lemmat]]
print(corpus)

# 0 refers to the document we are working with . we have here one document so it is 0 
doc = corpus[0]
print(doc)

# sort the document by frequency and indices 
bow_doc = sorted(doc,key=lambda w:w[1],reverse=True)
print(bow_doc)

# print the top 5 words of the documents alongside the count 
for word_id,word_count in bow_doc[:5]:
  print(dictionary.get(word_id),word_count)

from gensim.models.tfidfmodel import TfidfModel
tfidf = TfidfModel(corpus)
tfidf_weights = tfidf[doc]
print(tfidf_weights)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to apply the whole trained corpus within the tfidf model.
Second, you are getting an empty list because of the default value of the parameter `smartirs=nfc` in `models.tfidfmodel`. See the official API documentation [here](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/tfidfmodel.html).
That is due to the fact that your corpus contains only one document. I recommend using `Inverse collection frequency` then `smartirs=ntc`

For more information visit [SMART Information Retrieval System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMART_Information_Retrieval_System).

Here is the corrected part of the code with the new parameter `smartirs` value.

```
tfidf = TfidfModel(copus, smartirs='ntc')
tfidf_weights = tfidf[copus]
for doc in tfidf_weights:
    print([[dictionary[id], round(freq, 2)] for id, freq in doc])
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback and info... it worked.

Comment: @Johnny_Bee You are welcome. Please do not forget to accept the answer  (and/or upvote it) as it is working for you. Best.